# Как обратиться к элементу словаря, который находится в списке?

Tags: c#, list, коллекции, словари

Имеется следующий код, в котором список заполняется словарями

```
for (int i =  0;  i  < web_results.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> saveInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        saveInfo.Add("id", web_results[i++]);
        saveInfo.Add("firstname", web_results[i++]);
        saveInfo.Add("secondname", web_results[i++]);
        saveInfo.Add("jsondata", web_results[i++]);
        saveInfo.Add("group", web_results[i++]);
        saveInfo.Add("date", web_results[i]);
        Debug.Log((string)saveInfo["id"]);
        Debug.Log((string)saveInfo["date"]);

        saves.Add(saveInfo);
        saveInfo.Clear();
    }
```

Возможно ли обратиться к словарю в списке по ключу?  например обратиться  к первому  элементу листа,а затем по ключу получить значение из словаря

Comment: А в чем проблема и как вы пробовали?

Comment: проблема в том что я просто не знаю, как это сделать. Пробовал обращаться через индекс списка,  но это провальный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно.

```
for (int i =  0;  i  < web_results.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> saveInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    saveInfo.Add("id", web_results[i++]);
    saveInfo.Add("firstname", web_results[i++]);
    saveInfo.Add("secondname", web_results[i++]);
    saveInfo.Add("jsondata", web_results[i++]);
    saveInfo.Add("group", web_results[i++]);
    saveInfo.Add("date", web_results[i]);
    Debug.Log((string)saveInfo["id"]);
    Debug.Log((string)saveInfo["date"]);

    saves.Add(saveInfo);
    // saveInfo.Clear(); - !!!
}

Console.WriteLine(saves[0]["id"]);
```

Comment: очень благодарен вам

Comment: @Doot_Doot Пожалуйста. Успехов.